# Trouble multiplying recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion

I'm having trouble multiplying a long positive number such as `123241536287914341` with a constant positive number (such as `2`, `3`, ... `9`) in C using recursion. I understand how to multiply a long positive number by `10`, `100`, or so on, as you just need to add the appropriate amount of `0`s at the end. How would I do this when multiplying by `2`, `3`, `4`.... using two functions?

I.e. a function such as

```
char* multi(char *num1, char d)
```

along with a recursive helper function such as

```
void multi_helper(char *a, char *r, char b, int len, int carry)
```

This is the code I have for multiplying by `10`, but in a different format:

```
char *getmem(int len) {
    char *ret;
    ret = malloc(len);
    if (NULL == ret) {
        printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit (0);
    }
    else
        return ret;
}

char *shiftleft(char *a) {
    char *l = getmem(strlen(a)+2);
    strncpy(l,a,strlen(a));
    l[strlen(a)] = '0';
    l[strlen(a)+1] = 0;
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it appears that you want to 1.) Accept a number of arbitrary length (possibly greater than a long long) defined as a string, 2.) Multiply an integer constant by the value represented in the string, and 3.) Output the result of the multiplication as a string. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: you could try converting your string into a `long int`, multiply it, and then convert back

Comment: @SamIam isn't a long int the same size as int?

Comment: @SamIam I suspect his homework requires him to work with numbers too long for any built-in type.

Comment: You need to remember how you did multiplication by hand in grade school, and program that.

Comment: @statueuphemism That is correct.

Comment: Or simply use [gnump](http://gmplib.org/) and be happy - someone else already wrote this for you.

Comment: @SamIam I cannot use long int since the numbers are beyond the limits of long int.

Comment: @Barmar That's exactly the problem I'm not sure how to exactly do just that. I can sum two long positive numbers but can't seem to figure out how to multiply one of the long numbers say (123123123123) by a constant number say 3 recursively without explicitly having a bunch of if statements for each value I multiply by that has a 123123123123 added up that many times. For example what I mean is I don't want to have an if statement that says if l = 4 then add 123123123123 4 times because then I would need 7 if statements as well as multiple repetitions of the adding part of the code.

Comment: Break up your number into chunks that will fit within the built in data types.  Using the distributive property of multiplication, you can multiply individual pieces, then "add" them together by put them in a string or other type than can hold your big number.  You will need to worry slightly about carry across adds.

Comment: What's the problem with libgmp? Why can't you use it? Or is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Pass your count into your recursive function as a parameter.  Each level, subtract 1 before passing it to the next.  When at 0, break back out of your recursion and return the added value.  Assuming you have code than can add "big" numbers and that you don't try to multiply by 891748917 or something (stack overflow.)

Comment: How does this work for numbers larger than those able to be represented by integral types exactly? That said, I am not encouraging you to do someone else's homework.

Comment: He asked specifically about the handling recursion part above and I answered that here.  I had assumed he had some sort of "Big number Add" function given to him and was having trouble with recursion as a loop.  This helps with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very hastily written sloppy code which does this (on a reversed string; you can just reverse your number before and after calling it). Uses the same method of multiplying numbers you (hopefully) learned as a young child, which isn't *that* different from how numbers are multiplied in hardware...

```
// assumes number is reversed (for example, 100 would be represented as 001)
void mult_string(char *string, int multiplier, int carry)
{
    // If at end of number just add the carry digits one by one recursively
    if (*string == '\0')
    {
        if (carry == 0)
            return;
        unsigned short digit = carry%10;
        *string = (char)(digit + '0');
        // Will crash if string isn't long enough, you should address that if you actually use this code
        string[1] = '\0';
        mult_string(string + 1, multiplier, carry/10);
        return;
    }

    // Carry into next multiplication will be the tens digit of the current carry
    int newCarry = carry/10;
    unsigned short digit = *string - '0';
    unsigned short newDigit = digit * multiplier;
    // Add tens digit from result of multiplying the digit to carry
    newDigit += carry%10;
    newCarry += newDigit/10;
    newDigit %= 10;

    // Write out the multiplied digit
    *string = (char)(newDigit + '0');

    // Recursively multiply the rest of the string, with carry 
    mult_string(string + 1, multiplier, newCarry);
}
```

However, I would recommend NOT representing numbers as strings. It's pretty inefficient and unintuitive. If you need to store and operate on arbitrarily large numbers, there are many other people who have already solved the problem in far better ways, like with [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/), [bigint](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/bigint.git/), etc.